# BSOD: process1_initialization_failed

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, bsod

```
OS: Win7 Pro SP1 x86
Laptop: Dell Latitude E6410
```

Unable to boot into Windows and Safe Mode - both return the same blue screen. [Most](http://its.isber.ucsb.edu/troubleshooting/windows-7-bsod-process1initializationfailed) [online](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/process1initializationfailed-blue-screen-stop-06b/18250508-4ef2-4ddd-9599-ee1b11e32a32) [resources](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981833) explain that the `bootcat.cache` (in `%windir%\system32\CodeIntegrity\`) may be corrupt or the size of the file has unexpectedly changed.

Using a bootable Win7 USB drive and entering System Recovery Options, I can browse to this directory and see that there is no `bootcat.cache` file (even when looking at hidden system files). After all the attempts mentioned below were made, the machine does not create a new `bootcat.cache` file and, subsequently, will not boot into the OS.

I decided to create a valid copy of this file by recreating the OS using the same laptop. To do this, I removed the SSD from the laptop, inserted a new SSD, installed the same OS, booted into Windows (successfully), and copied the `bootcat.cache` file to a USB drive. I put the original SSD back into the laptop, put the new `bootcat.cache` file into the `CodeIntegrity` dir, and received the same BSOD.

[This](https://superuser.com/a/516250/254473) SU answer explains the `{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}` folder's relationship with the `bootcat.cache` file. I have completely replaced this folder with a copy from new SSD with no results.

[This](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0x0000006b/#Fix_1_Replace_the_DLL) article instructs to replace the `ntdll.dll` found in  `%windir%\system32`, which I have also copied from the new SSD with no results.

Other attempts made without results include,

- `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=E:\ /offwindir=E:\windows` (correct drive letter)
- delete McAfee from `ProgramFiles`
- [delete](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bootcatcache-becomes-corruptedchanged-every-time-i/cdcc2141-cc0f-44f2-81c6-78b067a86f86) `APSDaemon.exe` from `Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\`
- run Startup Repair

> "Windows cannot repair this computer automatically. Root cause found:
>   Unknown Bugcheck: Bugcheck 6b. Parameters = 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0. Repair
>   action: System files integrity check and repair. Result: Failed. Error
>   code = 0x490"

- (there are no System Restore points available)
- run Windows Memory Diagnostics
- MemTest86 (no errors)
- [rename](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsclub/fix_stop_0x0000006b_process1_initialization_failed_blue_screen/) `%windir%\system32\config\components`
- temporarily replace the `catroot`, `catroot2` and `CodeIntegrity` folders from the new SSD
- run [chkdsk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBYUS.jpg)
- run [Bootrec](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec.exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues). `/FixMbr` and `/FixBoot` completed successfully. `/ScanOs` and `/RebuildBcd` identify 0 Windows installations.

[image]

Comment: Any other error information on the BSOD besides `process1_initialization_failed`?

Comment: MS lists some causes in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx look what may apply to you

Comment: @Twisty Updated the original post.

Comment: Root - Have you already run a [Startup Repair](https://i.imgur.com/FwsgFXs.png) and just let it run to see if it finds any issues to resolve on it's own?  I also didn't see that you had run the `chkdsk C: /f` from the *System Recovery Options* [Command Prompt](https://i.imgur.com/KOztlH7.png) option?

Comment: @Walmart Startup Repair detects the bug check but cannot repair. I've added more details in the original post. I have also added `chkdsk` output to the original post. No luck there, either.

Comment: You might consider running the [BootRec](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec.exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues) `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, `bootrec /scanos` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd` commands from the recovery console to see if rebuilding the boot records, etc. has any positive impact to the issues.

Comment: @Walmart Updated the original post.

Comment: When you say you're able to boot using the Windows 7 USB drive, are you able to browse the HDD that is mounted too? If you could get a .dmp file that can be run through WinDBG, that would be a good start.

Comment: I also noticed you said this *I decided to create a valid copy of this file by recreating the OS using the same laptop. To do this, I removed the SSD from the laptop, inserted a new SSD, installed the same OS, booted into Windows (successfully).* So you clearly overcame the problem. Why did you not continue using the new SSD? There seems to be something faulty with the other one.

Comment: @DrZoo I was able to browse to the SSD that was having difficulty. Minidump logging was not enabled in the OS. I can't agree that replacing the SSD allowed me to overcome the problem. The goal was to fix what was broken, not replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue would go unsolved in this case. If you are stumbling upon this thread due to troubleshooting this error for yourself, I urge you not to get discouraged. Begin by following everything from the original post prior to the section labeled "Other attempts". There are a remarkable number of cases posted online exclaiming the `bootcat.cache` deletion/substitution is enough to boot the OS for further repair. I believe this particular laptop failed a system restore and went through the ringer with a local technician before reaching myself - it was a lost cause.

Let the original post in this thread serve as a conglomeration of resources and paths to troubleshoot when approaching this problem.

If stumped, do your due diligence and back up critical data and move on. Learn from my surprise - Nirsoft's portable key recovery application, [Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html), can run off a USB when using the command prompt from Startup Repair's advanced options. If nothing else, this will arm you with the original Windows key for reuse.

Answer (score 2):

The link by @magicandre1981 lists a bad disk as the main reason for this crash, which is logical as Startup Repair failed. SSD disks are fragile and may
fail (especially low-cost ones).

An SSD normally has lots of spare capacity to replace worn-out sectors.
When that capacity is exhausted the disk normally passes to read-only mode.
If that happened to you and if some crucial disk data was only partially
written to the disk, then data may be lost.

I suggest booting with the good SSD while installing the bad one as secondary
internal disk or if impossible in an external enclosure (less recommended),
then:

1. First backup all your data as much as possible,
   because this might be your last chance.
2. Install and invoke [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy)
   to review S.M.A.R.T. data for the disk.
   If too many errors exist
   the prognostic is not good.
   If you wish us to have a look, post a screenshot of this data.
3. Run `chkdsk`. If serious problems are found, either give up on the disk
   or try `chkdsk /f` - but be aware that this may just complete the destruction.
   For more information see this
   [howtogeek.com article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/).
4. Repair corrupted system files with the SFC command:

   a. Boot from your Windows install disc
   b. Click on Repair your computer after selecting proper language, time and keyboard input.
   c. Select the Windows installation drive, which is usually C:\, and click Next
   d. Choose Command Prompt when the System Recovery Options box appears
   e. Write the following command and press Enter:

`sfc /scannow /offbootdir=D:\ /offwindir=D:\Windows\`

5. Boot via the F8 menu and choose the "Last Known Good Configuration".
6. In another Windows 7 computer (or boot with the good disk), create a System Repair Disc by: Start, type system repair, select Create a System Repair Disc, and follow the prompts, then boot with it on the bad disk.
7. If all has failed, the SSD might be irreparable, or at least the Windows
   installation is unsalvageable.
   As a last effort you might try a clean install.
   (Note: The solution taken by the poster was similarly to give up and re-purpose the disk).

Comment: 2. I'm not convinced that the drive is damaged. All signs thus far point to corrupt OS files. No tests have reported any disk failure. 3. Done, updated the original post. 4. Done, the original post already had this information. 5. Looking into this now.

Comment: 5. I am reading that this is not an option unless you are able to boot into the OS. Regardless, I attempted this route anyway. `"Remove the installation disk and restart your computer so that Windows starts normally. Then, insert the installation disc and restart the upgrade".` http://superuser.com/questions/147472/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-windows-7-repair-install-when-you-are-unable-to-start-boo

Comment: Yes, the problem of the chicken and the egg. More to try: In another Windows 7 computer (or boot with the good disk) create a System Repair Disc by: Start, type system repair, select Create a System Repair Disc, and follow the prompts, then boot with it on the bad disk. Question: Can you boot via the F8 menu and choose the "Last Known Good Configuration"?

Comment: No, "Last Known Good Configuration" also will not boot. I have re-purposed the new SSD for an unrelated project. I created a bootable Win7 USB to continue. Booting from the USB, I cannot create a System Repair disk ("The files needed to create a system repair disc were not found on this computer"). I'm going to skip this route of troubleshooting. I appreciate your efforts. I am going to call time of death with this repair and format the drive. I have recovered all critical user files and product keys from the drive. Troubleshooting further is to beat a dead horse.